# unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize some results that i have found with grouping. I can get the plot right that i want but with the error that i keep getting in every factor that i have tried.

I used subplots for visualizing. I tried to do   `hash(tuple(numpy.array([1,2,3,4])))` but i don't know if i put it on the right place.

```
hash(tuple(numpy.array([1,2,3,4])))
countryfactor = df.groupby("country").sum()[["suicides/100k pop"]]
yearfactor = df.groupby("year").sum()[["suicides/100k pop"]]
sexfactor = df.groupby("sex").sum()[["suicides/100k pop"]]
agefactor = df.groupby("age").sum()[["suicides/100k pop"]]
hdifactor = df.groupby("HDI for year").sum()[["suicides/100k pop"]]
#gdpforyearfactor = df.groupby("gdp_for_year ($)").agg({"suicides_no" : sum})
hdifactor2 = pandas.pivot_table(df,"HDI for year","suicides/100k pop")
gdppercap = df.groupby("gdp_per_capita ($)").sum()[["suicides/100k pop"]]
generationfactor = df.groupby("generation").sum()[["suicides/100k pop"]]
continentsfactor = df.groupby("continents").sum()[["suicides/100k pop"]]
suicides = df.groupby("suicides/100k pop").max()
```

I am trying to find which factor affects the suicide ratio the most and i thought plotting would be a good idea to show that. If you have better idea to do that, i would be glad to do that.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(continentsfactor)
ax.plot(suicides)
legend = ax.legend(loc = "center right")
plt.xlabel("Continents")
plt.ylabel("suicides")
```

This is the code that causes the error.

Comment: Why do you want  to do  `hash(tuple(numpy.array([1,2,3,4])))`? In your example you don't assign the `hash()` return value to anything so it can't be used anyway.

Comment: `hash(tuple(numpy.array([1,2,3,4])))` works for me - it produces an int, not an Exception.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for me to do?

Comment: Post the code that generated the error and the whole stack trace please. Somewhere in the code you are passing a numpy array to a data type that cannot be indexed with numpy arrays (for example a dictionary).

Comment: It seems impossible for anyone to provide a suggestion since you haven't shown what you are using the hash for AND that statement should not produce an Exception so it really isn't clear what you are asking.